# how to display database records even when cell is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i'm here again to ask help regarding my problem with the view that i created. 
On my tblEvents there 8 records but i created the view it only displays 3 records. I'am suspecting that the view doesn't read a null value from my tblEvents. How do i fix this?[alt text http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/143/vwevents.png](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/143/vwevents.png)

[alt text http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/8418/tblevents.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/8418/tblevents.png)

```
SELECT dbo.tblUsers.UserID, 
           dbo.tblUsers.UserFirstName + ' UserLastName' AS Author, 
           dbo.tblUsers.UserLastName, 
           dbo.tblUsers.UserEmailAddress,
           dbo.tblEvents.EventID,
           dbo.tblEvents.EventName, 
           dbo.tblEvents.EventDescription, 
           dbo.tblEvents.EventVenue,
           dbo.tblEvents.EventDate, 
           dbo.tblEvents.AddedBy, 
           dbo.tblEvents.Pending, 
           dbo.tblEvents.DateAdded, 
           dbo.tblEvents.DateEditted, 
           dbo.tblUsers.UserName
  FROM dbo.tblUsers 
    JOIN dbo.tblEvents ON dbo.tblUsers.UserID = dbo.tblEvents.EdittedBy
```

Comment: And if this is a new table, please fix the field DateEditted to ne correctly spelled as DateEdited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that if the record has not been edited, then you want to join on the `AddedBy` column. See below:

```
SELECT 
    u.UserID, 
    u.UserFirstName + ' UserLastName' AS Author, 
    u.UserLastName, 
    u.UserEmailAddress, 
    e.EventID,
    e.EventName, 
    e.EventDescription, 
    e.EventVenue, 
    e.EventDate, 
    e.AddedBy, 
    e.Pending, 
    e.DateAdded, 
    e.DateEditted, 
    u.UserName
FROM dbo.tblUsers u
INNER JOIN dbo.tblEvents e ON u.UserID = ISNULL(e.EdittedBy, e.AddedBy)
```

Comment: Functions in joins should be avoided. Very poor performers.

Answer (score 2):

@RedFilter's answer sounds good to me.  But, if it's not appropriate to join on the `AddedBy` column, then you can change the join to an outer join.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblEvents ON dbo.tblUsers.UserID = dbo.tblEvents.EdittedBy
```

Answer (score 0):

use LEFT OUTER JOIN

SELECT dbo.tblUsers.UserID, 
           dbo.tblUsers.UserFirstName + ' UserLastName' AS Author, 
           dbo.tblUsers.UserLastName, 
           dbo.tblUsers.UserEmailAddress,
           dbo.tblEvents.EventID,
           dbo.tblEvents.EventName, 
           dbo.tblEvents.EventDescription, 
           dbo.tblEvents.EventVenue,
           dbo.tblEvents.EventDate, 
           dbo.tblEvents.AddedBy, 
           dbo.tblEvents.Pending, 
           dbo.tblEvents.DateAdded, 
           dbo.tblEvents.DateEditted, 
           dbo.tblUsers.UserName
  FROM dbo.tblEvents 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblUsers ON dbo.tblEvents.EdittedBy= dbo.tblUsers.UserID

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to propose a slightly different solution based on a slightly different assumption. Assuming that you want to return users and all the events that they have either added or edited:

```
SELECT dbo.tblUsers.UserID, 
               dbo.tblUsers.UserFirstName + ' UserLastName' AS Author, 
               dbo.tblUsers.UserLastName, 
               dbo.tblUsers.UserEmailAddress,
               dbo.tblEvents.EventID,
               dbo.tblEvents.EventName, 
               dbo.tblEvents.EventDescription, 
               dbo.tblEvents.EventVenue,
               dbo.tblEvents.EventDate, 
               dbo.tblEvents.AddedBy, 
               dbo.tblEvents.Pending, 
               dbo.tblEvents.DateAdded, 
               dbo.tblEvents.DateEditted, 
               dbo.tblUsers.UserName
      FROM dbo.tblUsers 
        JOIN dbo.tblEvents ON dbo.tblUsers.UserID = dbo.tblEvents.AddedBy
    UNION
    SELECT dbo.tblUsers.UserID, 
               dbo.tblUsers.UserFirstName + ' UserLastName' AS Author, 
               dbo.tblUsers.UserLastName, 
               dbo.tblUsers.UserEmailAddress,
               dbo.tblEvents.EventID,
               dbo.tblEvents.EventName, 
               dbo.tblEvents.EventDescription, 
               dbo.tblEvents.EventVenue,
               dbo.tblEvents.EventDate, 
               dbo.tblEvents.AddedBy, 
               dbo.tblEvents.Pending, 
               dbo.tblEvents.DateAdded, 
               dbo.tblEvents.DateEditted, 
               dbo.tblUsers.UserName
      FROM dbo.tblUsers 
        JOIN dbo.tblEvents ON dbo.tblUsers.UserID = dbo.tblEvents.EdittedBy
```